# Delete folders from HDFS in dd-MM-yyyy format for a year

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How do I delete a bunch of directories in hadoop by year? The folder is created daily. The name scheme is "dd-mm-yyyy". How do I delete folders of a particular year? I tried getting the list of folders like hadoop fs -find / "*1995" but I am unable to delete them by piping them to the rm command.

Comment: Ideally you should store yyyy-MM-dd format...

Comment: Did you try using xargs in your pipe command?

Comment: I tried something like this hadoop fs -rm -R | hadoop fs -find --------- . PS: I'm very new to hadoop and linux.

Comment: That pipe is backwards. You want to find the folders, then pipe that list to the rm command `hdfs dfs -find... | xargs hdfs dfs -rm -R`

Comment: My bad! I didn't realize that at all! I'll try this out asap. Thanks for your help cricket!

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop CLI supports both recursive `rm` (needed to delete directories) and wildcards:

```
hadoop fs -rm -r -f /path/*-1995
```

Comment: Thanks! Ill try this as well!